# mysql sum and count 2 tables group by issue

Tags: mysql

Table A

```
id  | s_id      | unit_value
-----------------------------
1   | S01       | 5
2   | S01       | 8
3   | S01       | 6
4   | S01       | 3
5   | S02       | 9
```

Table B

```
id  | a_id      | price
------------------------
1   | 2         | 900
2   | 2         | 100
3   | 2         | 600
4   | 3         | 100
5   | 5         | 100
6   | 1         | 10
7   | 1         | 200
8   | 4         | 100
9   | 4         | 200
```

need result as

```
s_id    |  total_price  | total_unit  | count(s_id)
----------------------------------------------------
SO1     |    2210       |      22     |   4
SO2     |    100        |      9      |   1
```

For this I have tried query as

```
SELECT a.s_id
     , SUM(b.price) AS total_price
     , SUM(a.unit_value) AS total_unit
     , COUNT(s_id)
  FROM A a
  JOIN B b 
    ON b.a_id = a.id 
 GROUP 
    BY a.s_id
```

Can anyone help me how to achieve the correct result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Add the prices up in a subquery for B

> ```
> SELECT a.s_id
>      , SUM(b.price) AS total_price
>      , SUM(a.unit_value) AS total_unit
>      , COUNT(s_id)
>   FROM A a
>   JOIN (SELECT SUM(price) price , a_id FROM B GROUP BY a_id) b  
>     ON b.a_id = a.id 
>  GROUP 
>     BY a.s_id
> ```

> ```
> s_id | total_price | total_unit | COUNT(s_id)
> :--- | ----------: | ---------: | ----------:
> S01  |        2210 |         22 |           4
> S02  |         100 |          9 |           1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4370a9b3410873b2d62f58a856160093)*

Answer (score 1):

Next query can solve the problem:

```
SELECT a.s_id
     , SUM(b.price) AS total_price
     , total_unit
     , count_s_id
  FROM A a
  JOIN B b ON b.a_id = a.id 
  JOIN (
    -- join pre-grouped table
    SELECT
        s_id,
        SUM(A.unit_value) AS total_unit,
        COUNT(s_id) count_s_id 
    FROM A GROUP BY s_id
  ) grouped_a ON grouped_a.s_id = a.s_id
 GROUP 
    BY a.s_id;
```

Test it on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=5dfc8d3a9fda0c46620c6220780211b4&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)